# Traceflag 647 Needed Despite Using Sparse Columns

Tags: sql-server, sparse-matrix, sql-server-2016

I am using SQL Server 2016 SP1 and have a database that contains a table with sparse columns. 
There are approx 1500 sparse columns and about 10 non sparse columns. Most of these sparse columns are nvarchar(1000).

I have noticed that suddenly it is taking a long time to add new sparse columns to this table.  SP_whoisactive is indicating a high number of reads and sp_lock indicates that exclusive key locks are being taken out on sys.sysrscols.

I have found this [fix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2986423/fix-it-takes-a-long-time-to-add-new-columns-to-a-table-when-the-row-si) that indicates that once a table has rows that reach a size close to the maximum in-row size, when a new column is added, a full scan of the table to make sure that adding a new column does not violate the data integrity.

A backwards compatibility traceflag is provided to override this behaviour which was introduced in SQL Server 2012 and applying that traceflag has fixed the problem.  However, I don't feel I should need to apply this traceflag to the instance as further down the page, Microsoft state that

"You can consider adding variable length columns or sparse columns when your application frequently adds new columns to the table. It is a metadata-only operation even if the total size of all columns exceeds 8,060 bytes."

DBCC ShowContig indicates a maximum row size of 2736 so I don't see that I should be getting this issue, despite using sparse columns.

Anybody come across this before? I can provide a definition of the table if required but it is obviously pretty big...

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same behavior you described and found your post: Adding a sparse, fixed-size column was very slow.

Furthermore, I found that adding a variable length column (e.g. `nvarchar(100) null`) was also slow, which contradicts the other half of that statement.

However, when I add a column that is both variable length *and* sparse (e.g. `nvarchar(100) sparse null`), it is fast (indicating that it is metadata-only).

Maybe this was a typo, although that bullet-point was written as a potential workaround, and resorting to just using variable-length, sparse columns doesn't sound viable in many situations.